# Django - login_required doesn't update URL

Tags: python, django, authentication, decorator

I'm currently facing issues using `@login_required` django decorator.

Indeed, using `@login_required` correctly redirect to the page I want, but didn't update the URL.

I've requested login to access 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/global_results/by_module/'

```
@login_required
def results_by_module(request):
...
```

When I'm going to this page without logging in, the page I see is the correct one (login), but the URL is not updated (still http://127.0.0.1:8000/global_results/by_module/) whereas I see the correct redirection into django logs:

```
[20/Nov/2018 11:41:08] "GET /global_results/by_module/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[20/Nov/2018 11:41:08] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/global_results/by_module/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2055
```

When I refresh the page, I can see the 'correct' url http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/global_results/by_module/

What am I doing wrong? I tried to use

```
def results_by_module(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('accounts/login/?next=%s' % request.path)
```

or

```
def results_by_module(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('accounts/login/?next=%s' % request.path)
```

with always the same behaviour.

Comment: Are you using Ajax anywhere?

Comment: Nope. I'm using django-material framework (https://github.com/viewflow/django-material)
I've just found that this is working fine if I put the `@login_required`on 'parent' page `global_results`

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this issue by adding `data-turbolinks="false"` into all my html href tag.

\o/